# Is Careers suitable if I want to become an intern?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I'm still in university and in the coming years I expect to be looking at getting an internship somewhere.

Would you guys recommend Careers here for that kind of thing? Is it worth the money to put a CV up and is it popular enough to hopefully land me something?

I've never used Careers and am not sure if many employers look for interns through it.

Answer (score 6):

I think it certainly wouldn't hurt (but then, I would say that, wouldn't I?)

Seriously though, since you're a student it's free to file your CV, and it's a great way to show that you're serious about your craft. So even if you have to send it along to employers when you're reaching out to them (rather than them finding you on careers) you'll still have a leg up on those that don't have a Stack Overflow CV.

In addition, you *will* show up in search results. Companies have been known to look for interns (no stats, sorry) and having a CV on Stack Overflow will tell them you're serious about getting a great job (or possibly a great internship for starters), and that you know what you're doing.

Finally, your CV will be marked as "student". If I had a company with an internship program and I would see a great student on SO Careers while doing another search, I'd file them away for future reference.

Good luck!